# AngularJS ng-reapeat does not render in browser

Tags: angularjs

**My browser only renders : "{{ cust.name + ',' + cust.city }}"**

**index.html**

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html data-ng-app="demoApp">
        <head>
            <meta charset="utf-8">
            <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge">


            <title></title>
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

            <style>
                html, body, input, select, textarea
                {
                    font-size: 1em;            
                }
            </style>

        </head>

        <body>

            <div data-ng-controller="SimpleController">
                Name :
                <br>
                <input type="text" data-ng-model="name">
                <br>

                <ul>
                    <li data-ng-repeat="cust in customers">{{ cust.name + ',' + cust.city }}</li>
                </ul>
            </div>    

            <script>

                var demoApp = angular.module('demoApp', []);

                var controllers = {};
                controllers.SimpleController = function ($scope) {
                    $scope.customers = [
                        {name:'John', city:'Paris'}, 
                        {name:'Andy La', city:'Londra'}, 
                        {name:'George', city:'Berlin'}
                    ];
                });

                demoApp.controller(controllers);

            </script>

        </body>
        <script src="Scripts/angular.min.js"></script> 

    </html>
```

Its something wrong with my code??? Any ideea what can i do?
I have tryed some other ideeas from other sites and other people but it doesn't work. I dont know what do do anymore. 
I am quite new with angularJS!

Thanks!

Comment: try to put your <script src="Scripts/angular.min.js"></script>  in the header, not after your angular script

Comment: Thank you a lot. Pb solved :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to refer the angular.js script inside the **`body`** tag

Also you have extra paranthesis at the end, remove it.

**DEMO**

```js
var demoApp = angular.module('demoApp', []);
 var controllers = {};
 controllers.SimpleController = function ($scope) {
  $scope.customers = [
   {name:'John', city:'Paris'}, 
   {name:'Andy La', city:'Londra'}, 
   {name:'George', city:'Berlin'}
  ];
};
demoApp.controller(controllers);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.5/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="demoApp" ng-controller="SimpleController">
 Name :
  <br>
   <input type="text" data-ng-model="name">
  <br>
 <ul>
  <li data-ng-repeat="cust in customers">{{ cust.name + ',' + cust.city }}</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: It works! Thank you a milion times. Small details that change everything :) I changed the code in many ways and i didnt find the pb.

Comment: Ok! I did that! Thank you again!